# find with xargs runs successfully but no changes to file

Tags: find, batch-processing, xargs

I run a command to batch process image files using resmushit:

`find /home/user/image/data -type f -print0 | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -0 resmushit -q 85 --preserve-filename`

The command runs successfully and tells me the files were optimized and saved however when I check the files in the folder there is no change.

edit: it looks like the problem might be with resmushit. When I run it on pictures within my working directory it works. i.e

`resmushit -q 85 --preserve-filename test.jpg`

Is there a way to make xargs or a different command to run the command within each folder recursively?

Answer (score 0):

I ended finding for directories and using a bash file so:

`find /home/user/image/data -type d -print0 | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -0 bashscript`

and the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$*"
resmushit -q 85 --preserve-filename *
```